# Rails 3.2 to 4.0 upgrade issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Iam new to ruby on rails and is trying to upgrade a legacy project having rails version 3.2 to 4.0. Iam incrementally upgrading versions to reach rails 6 version. I changed rails version in gem file to 4.0 (gem lock has old version 3.2) and executed command bundle update rails. It gives me following error for mongoid_rails_integrations.

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
    json

    aws-sdk (~> 1.34.1) was resolved to 1.34.1, which depends on
      json (~> 1.4)

    carrierwave-video was resolved to 0.5.6, which depends on
      carrierwave was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
        json (>= 1.7)

    mongoid-simple-tags was resolved to 0.1.3, which depends on
      json (~> 1.8)

    simplecov was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
      json (>= 1.8, < 3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mongoid":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    mongoid (= 3.1.7)

  In Gemfile:
    mongoid-rspec (>= 1.4.6) was resolved to 1.13.0, which depends on
      mongoid (~> 3.1)

    mongoid_rails_migrations was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      mongoid (>= 4.0.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0)

    mongoid_rails_migrations was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.2.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0)

    sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) was resolved to 3.2.6, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
```

But my question is mongoid_rails_migrations depends on rails version greater than 3.2, which is true for rails 4.0 . Then why this errror occurs. Any one please help me to figure out will be appreciable.

Comment: Is this the complete error message?

Comment: @Oleg I have updated my question. It shows other dependencies also. But confusing part is with mongoid_rails_migrations

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use same version of sass-rails as rails gem i-e if you are using rails 4.0.0 then use same version of sass-rails. Similarly also make sure to use same version for coffee-rails and update uglifier in your Gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

P.S. Sorry I am not able to post comment due to low reputation.

Comment: I tried out updating bundler to 2.0.0, it didn't work. as rails 4.0.0 depends on bundler < 2,i downgraded it again to 1.17.3. it was initially 1.16.3.

Comment: do i need to delete gem lock before install after commenting out all gems except rails. I dont need all gems to get updated to latest version. Iam doing incremental update,ie from rails 3.2 to 4.0,4.0 to 4.1 untill rails 6.

Comment: is there any way to figure out which gem is causing compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of conflicting requirements in your current upgrade attempt. I suggest starting with the easier ones to fix, then coming back to rails.

```
aws-sdk (~> 1.34.1) was resolved to 1.34.1, which depends on
  json (~> 1.4)
```

Try loosening aws-sdk version first so that you can use json 1.8.

```
sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) was resolved to 3.2.6, which depends on
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
```

Try loosening sass-rails version so that this part goes away.

```
mongoid-rspec (>= 1.4.6) was resolved to 1.13.0, which depends on
  mongoid (~> 3.1)

mongoid_rails_migrations was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
  mongoid (>= 4.0.0)
```

This could be a problem, but deal with the stuff I mentioned earlier first.

Originally I thought you *might* need to update rails, active* and railties together since their versions are locked. The current message doesn't necessarily suggest this but you may try giving it a go nonetheless.

> do i need to delete gem lock before install

Not advised. You may get updates that satisfy the constraints in the gemfile that break your application. When one is trying to update an ancient application like this, it is generally a very good idea to consciously consider every single dependency and what the impact of its version change is likely to be.